Can I put a rock I found outside in my saltwater aquarium?
Should aquarist ever put rocks found outside in their aquarium? Is there a method to test if a rock is safe for usage?



What I see int he picture looks like some cemented mud loosely incorporating some white pebbles. While interesting, I would consider this as "garbage" for my aquarium.
As an alternative, if you want something similar, find a pottery place (workshop, school etc.) end create there any "stone" you want. After "cooking" the clay (about 1000 deg Celsius in special oven), the clay should be quite OK for the aquarium. You also have the option to apply transparent or colored coatings on those pottery objects.


Is there a method to test if a rock is safe for usage?

(jokingly) Just put it into the aquarium. If the fish suddenly start dying, then most likely the stone is not safe.
One test that I know of is like this: put some vinegar on the stone. If it starts to make bubbles, it means the stone has a lot of calcium, and is not safe. There must be other tests also, but I do not know them.


cemented mud loosely incorporating some white pebbles

It looks really pretty but I am concerned it may fall apart.

Well, mud (as well other things) do have the bad habit of falling apart when wet. Salty or not.

And whatever you do, before putting it into an acquarium sterilise it thoroughly by boiling it for an extended period. Personally I'd also let it sit in chlorine bleach for a few days, then brush it very well under running water and then sterilise it in boiling water.

@jwenting: That might be a bit of overdoing, but it is in the good direction. Better safe than sorry.
